# Object contents modified in method but object hashcode remains the same

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In this piece of code i pass a name into a method that modifies the String literal `name` but not the object itself, when the code exits the method, the object (as identified by the hashcode) is the same, however not the `name` that is modified in the method.

How should i explain this?

```
public class ObjectContentsPassByReferenceApp {
    private static void modifyObject(Bus bus) {
        bus.setName("SBS Transit");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Bus bus;

        bus = new Bus();
        bus.setName("Trans Island Bus");

        System.out.println("Bus initially set to (hashcode): " + bus);
        System.out.println("Bus name: " + bus.getName());

        modifyObject(bus);

        System.out.println("After calling modifyObject (hashcode): " + bus);
        System.out.println("Bus name: " + bus.getName());
    }
}

class Bus {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Run results:

```
Bus initially set to (hashcode): sg.java.concepts.passByReference.Bus@8d2ed0
Bus name: Trans Island Bus
After calling modifyObject (hashcode): sg.java.concepts.passByReference.Bus@8d2ed0
Bus name: SBS Transit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't overridden `hashCode` - therefore it will use the implementation in `java.lang.Object`, which *doesn't* vary over the course of an object's lifetime. You haven't overridden `equals` either... which means that `a.equals(b)` will only return `true` for `Bus a` and `Bus b` if `a` and `b` refer to the exact same object - rather than objects with equal name.

Note that the names in your code suggest that Java uses pass by reference. It doesn't - it always uses pass by value, but those values are always either primitives or references - never actual objects. The same is true for simple assignment etc.

In your code, you're creating a *single* `Bus` object. Think of it as a real life bus. It has a name painted on it, and a serial number embossed on it (the latter being the hash code). When you call the method, that's telling the method how to *get* to the `Bus` object - it's not creating a new `Bus`. The method comes and paints over the name with a new one, but that does nothing to the serial number, which is the same as it ever was.

Also note that `name` is not a string literal - it's a string *variable*. Its initial value comes from a string literal, but changing the value later does nothing to the original string object.

Comment: Hi Jon, will this have anything to do with the "mutability" of String?

Comment: @Chin: Which bit? The hash code staying the same? Absolutely not. You haven't overridden the `hashCode` method, so it *will* stay the same over the course of the object's lifetime no matter what you do. Changing `String` to its mutable cousin `StringBuilder` wouldn't affect that at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the hashcode to depend on a variable (i.e. `name`) then you'll need to override the `hashCode` method. A simple example:

```
public class Bus {
    private String name;

    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

The `hashCode` implementation in `java.lang.Object` does not use any kind of reflection to look up variables, so you almost always need to override `hashCode`.

Note that you should *always* override `equals` if you override `hashCode` and vice versa.

There are a bunch of useful tools for helping you implement `hashCode`. Check out [Apache Commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and take a look at their `HashCodeBuilder` class.